# how to set id of rectangle in Builder python kivy?

Tags: python, graphics, kivy, builder

I want to have opportunity to change or delete rectangle in builder, but I get AttributeError.
How can I fix it? I hope you help me

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>
    FloatLayout:
        id: layout
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                id: image
                size: (100, 180)
                pos: (223, 191)
                source:'image.gif'
''')
class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.image)

class WindowApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WindowApp().run()
```

Comment: What is the final result you want to achieve? Maybe there is a more easy way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't set the `id` of a canvas object. Here is a workaround: Consider you want to change the `source` attribute of your Rectangle. Set `rectangle_image: "image.gif"` in your `FloatLayout`, then set `source: self.rectangle_image` in your Rectangle. Now you can reference the `FloatLayout` by its `id` and change its `rectangle_image` variable, and it will automatically update the Rectangle's `source` attribute!

Comment: I can't believe that worked. :) It's been surprisingly hard to find a way in Kivy, to change a background declared in kv-lang.